# How Send WriteableBitmap as byte[] from silverlight client and deserialize to Bitmap on server side?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I sending WriteableBitmap as byte[] from silverlight client - and i want to deserialize the byte[] to Bitmap or Image object in the server side.

How do i deserialize  this byte[] ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a method on your WCF service that takes byte[] as a parameter. Have your Silverlight app call that and pass the bytes in.

On the server side, the Image class has a constructor that takes a Stream. So you can create a new MemoryStream(byte[]) with the bytes, and then call Image.FromStream() with the new MemoryStream.

There's probably several other ways to do this, but that one should work.